# Square Web Payment SDK how do I set the amount value in the form

Tags: javascript, html, square

I'm trying to create a money payment form using the Square Web Payment SDK.

But I don't know where the amount to be paid is placed. All the examples I've seen so far do not indicate where or how the amount to be paid is set.

I'm new to the Square payment API.

Need your help.

Thanks in advance!

My current HTML code looks like below:

```html
<form id="payment-form">
<div id="card-container"></div>
<button id="card-button" type="button">Pay</button>
</form>
<div id="payment-status-container"></div>

<script type="module">
    const payments = Square.payments('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXX');
    const card = await payments.card();
    await card.attach('#card-container');

    const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    cardButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      const statusContainer = document.getElementById('payment-status-container');

      try {
        const result = await card.tokenize();
        if (result.status === 'OK') {
          console.log(`Payment token is ${result.token}`);
          statusContainer.innerHTML = `Payment Successful`;
        } else {
          let errorMessage = `Tokenization failed with status: ${result.status}`;
          if (result.errors) {
            errorMessage += ` and errors: ${JSON.stringify(
              result.errors
            )}`;
          }

          throw new Error(errorMessage);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        statusContainer.innerHTML = "Payment Failed";
      }
    });
</script>
<script src="https://sandbox.web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js"></script>
```